# Typescript - Set object value based on object property key type

Tags: typescript

## I have a redux store, where I want to have a reducer that is able to change any attribute values in the store.

Take the following `state` object with a type:

```
type StoreState = {
  admins: Admin[];
  messages: Message[];
  pageInformation: PageInformation;
}

const state: StoreState = {
  admins: [],
  messages: [],
  pageInformation: {},
}
```

Imagine a function that is not a reducer.
For the sake of this example it doesn't matter.

```
const setPropertyValue = ({ propName, propValue }) => {
  state[propName] = propValue;
}
```

In the given function, I would like to give a type to `propName`, and `propValue`.

Let's say if the value of `propName` is "admins", then `propValue` would be the value of `StoreState[propName]`, so `Admin[]`:

```
setPropertyValue({ propName: "admins", propValue: [...] });
```

## I have tried a few solutions, and researched multiple sources, but as far as I have seen Typescript does not allow to do such thing.

Here is one example:

```
type SetPropertyValue = {
  propName: keyof StoreState;
  propValue: StoreState[SetPropertyValue[propName]];
}

const setPropertyValue = ({ propName, propValue }: SetPropertyValue) => {
  state[propName] = propValue;
}
```

This example would fail, because `propName` is not actually a key of `StoreState`, but rather a union type with the keys of `StoreState`.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is [type parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#generic-functions) for your `setPropertyValue` function (constrained by keys in your store). This way TS will be able to infer required type for `propValue` based on passed `propName`:

```
type Admin = number;
type Message = string;
type PageInformation = {};

type StoreState = {
  admins: Admin[];
  messages: Message[];
  pageInformation: PageInformation;
}

const setPropertyValue = <T extends keyof StoreState>({ propName, propValue }: {propName: T, propValue: StoreState[T]}) => {};

setPropertyValue({propName: 'admins', propValue: [1, 2, 3]}); // Works
setPropertyValue({propName: 'messages', propValue: ['hey', 'hello', 'hola']}); // Works
setPropertyValue({propName: 'admins', propValue: ['hey', 'hello', 'hola']}); // Doesn't work
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=15&ssc=93&pln=11&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAggJgWwJYDsoF4ooK4IEYQBOA3AFCiRQCyEAzrQIYDm0mtwhqTZF0ACswgBJFADMA9oQQNgScWkwBvAL5ly4aAGVgkiNpmsoi0lCgNEqWgC5YFlAG0AumVMI6jFtervBTl1DBBEQkpGTkUGwEWYMlpWXkyZVJSAGN5dihaCGA+QnFIQlAANQYAG2xDAB4AFSgIAA9gCBQ4WigAawgQcVEobV19JoA+AApFALywADkGNwAaCfyS8uhlG0UwSZm3G2qFzaWyipt+wj1gA3tqx2UASgwho1VkrJzJomKjiDGD6dmIGwAcnMyBQtEB+0my2OUHsAEYFgAmBYAZhut2IUAA9FioAB1STtWikV65fIfEDQ74bLb-IFueiCcGQw4rGz2QEACy6EKgXIgpVK4l5XPEpQYgPRmJx+MJxNJ70KlK+P1pOz5IMsvN+VPZ-JAIu5guFC1F4sld2luIAIuI6ChAcAoAB3QlAA)